# send email using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Severity: Warning

Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1894

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\prmadmin\application\controllers\Email.php
Line: 49
Function: send

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\prmadmin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Edit your question with the code where you send the email.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this:**

```
public function send_mail(){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $to_email = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $from_email = 'xyz@gmail.com';

    $config = array(
                    'charset' => 'utf-8',
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                    'mailtype' => 'html'
                );

    $this->email->initialize($config);

     $this->email->from($from_email);
                $this->email->to($to_email);
                $this->email->subject('Test mail send');
                $this->email->message('Test Mail);

    if($this->email->send()){
    echo "send";
    }else{
    echo "error";
    }
}
```